# Why does file.exists return FALSE despite being in list.files?

Tags: r, windows, file-access

I have a file `x` which appears in a directory, as proved by `list.files`

```
x <- "./data-raw/paths/calculate-route-by-FROM-TO/2017-05-2075--FROM-Flinders-Street-Railway-Station--Melbourne-Victoria-3004--VIC--TO-Melbourne-Sports-Aquatic-Centre--30-Aughtie-Dr--Melbourne-VIC-3206--VIC-csv"
x %in% list.files("./data-raw/paths", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
# [1] TRUE
file.exists(x)
# [1] FALSE
```

Note that `x` lacks an extension, but I could not find such a caveat in `?file.exists`:

> `file.exists` returns a logical vector indicating whether the files named by its argument exist. (Here ‘exists’ is in the sense of the system's `stat` call: a file will be reported as existing only if you have the permissions needed by stat. Existence can also be checked by `file.access`, which might use different permissions and so obtain a different result. Note that the existence of a file does not imply that it is readable: for that use `file.access`.) What constitutes a ‘file’ is system-dependent, but should include directories. (However, directory names must not include a trailing backslash or slash on Windows.) Note that if the file is a symbolic link on a Unix-alike, the result indicates if the link points to an actual file, not just if the link exists. Lastly, note the different function exists which checks for existence of R objects.

The only hint from the documentation was that access restrictions might cause `FALSE`, and indeed `file.access(x)` is `-1` but I appear to have access to that file (as well as other very similar files which are not so affected).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows has an upper limit on the length of a filename (260 characters), which `x` exceeded. Shortening the file resulted in `file.exists` returning `TRUE`.